# Remove Action On Empty PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm sure this is an easy question but I am a beginner. I've figured out how to display my ACF info (woohooo) but if the field is blank the echo needs to be removed.  I am not sure how to go about adding that in.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', "ACF_product_content", 5 );
    function ACF_product_content(){
        if (function_exists('the_field')){
        echo '<h2 class="dd-tiff">Delivery Date: ';
        the_field('ti-date');
        echo '</h2>';

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', "ACF_product_content", 5 );
function ACF_product_content(){

    if (function_exists('the_field')){
    $ti_date = get_field('ti-date');
    if($ti_date){
        echo '<h2 class="dd-tiff">Delivery Date: ';
        the_field('ti-date');
        echo '</h2>';
     }

  }

}
```

Try this code

Comment: @samonella  did you checked the loophole

Comment: @samonella  please ask a new question. We can't answer here, because the question have already one marked answer.Thanks

Comment: @samonella  meanwhile you can check my answer which have no loopwholes

Comment: @Avant Ahh pushed enter too fast. If I'm calling tif-date how do I call $date too? I'm confused. Ok I will ask a new one thank you!

Comment: @Avant I got it! Thank you for responding so quickly!

Comment: @samonella  it's anant not Avant

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', "ACF_product_content", 5);
function ACF_product_content(){
    if (function_exists('the_field')){
    if(!is_null(the_field('ti-date')) || strlen(the_field('ti-date')) != 0){
      echo '<h2 class="dd-tiff">Delivery Date: ';
      the_field('ti-date');
      echo '</h2>';
    }


  }

}
```